# Network latency tester

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-7, latency

Anyone know how I can test network latency in C#? I'm using the WP7.1 (Mango) CF, so the `Ping` class isn't available unless I dig into reflector and extract it. (blech)

Comment: What would you do with this information if you had it?

Comment: I'm streaming data from the phone over WiFi to a PC on the same subnet.  I'm trying to determine if the lag I'm seeing is a latency problem or If there's a performance issue with my code.

Comment: @David When you want to test your code build a reference implementation with only the important socket part on Windows and you can profile that code etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cant build your own Ping class with Sockets because Mango's sockets not support custom IP headers.

You can build your own ping service which do basically the same as ping only with TCP or UDP packets and custom data in the packets. But then your endpoint must provide your own server implementation.

Comment: I'm not trying to create Ping. I'm trying to measure latency. There has to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just eyeball it... send a "on" packet when your finger is on the screen, and "off" when not. Have the PC-side do something obvious to you like change a window from green/red.